# Clients domain does not load in china, instead another site loads

Tags: domains, amazon-aws, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, problem

Clients domain tiandilatex.com works fine and is available worldwide, but has problems loading in China. The site is replaced by the first image below, an entertainment blog type website according to my client (Screen shot is from clients computer in China)

I'm hosting the site on an AWS EC2 instance located in Virginia, USA.

I'm looking at opening another EC2 instance in Singapore just for the site maybe, or using S3 to host the site, but I'm not sure if this is the right option to fix this issue. Any suggestions most welcome.

[image: View from clients computer in China]
[image: Not blocked according to this check]

Comment: Have you called the host and asked them? It seems like something that is on the hosts end.

Comment: @closetnoc OP appears to *be* the host.  *"I'm hosting the site..."*

Comment: Testing the site with "blocked in China" proves little.  Without evidence to prove otherwise, they're only testing that *something* is accessible... which you already know, from the screen shot. *Something* is indeed accessible at your domain, in China.  I'm not sure why you're thinking Singapore would help, so you might clarify that.  It's easy and cheap enough to test.  You could even do it with a proxy in Singapore that connects back to us-east-1.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No. Not actually. The OP is using a hosting service with a fairly complex structure and network. Hosting your own means you own the network and servers with have full control over every aspect of it. In this case, I believe that the OP should call Amazon, the host. The host should be able to trace requests through their network.

Comment: Well, I see what you are saying, but there's no reason to think this needs to be escalated to AWS.  Basic troubleshooting hasn't been done -- what address does the client in China get from DNS?  If that answer is wrong, then the site's likely being highjacked via DNS behind the wall, and there's nothing for AWS to trace.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The client gets the correct address, but not the right page. Singapore is the closest AWS server to China so it might help if latency is the issue. DNS may be hijacked, maybe not maliciously, other tests I've done show the ping is really slow > 120 sec, so it could even be the ISP loading a branded page instead of a standard error page. I think I will contact AWS because I don't want to waste time setting up a solution that ultimately doesn't fix the problem, seems this is something new and not many have experienced it yet. Not much online about this issue either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just checked with several DNS lookup tools that the address is not tampered with in China. 
I have even loaded the website using a Chinese proxy. Again, all is normal.
I suspect that the client simply has some adware infection. If there is some proxying going on, it's a small affair, one ISP at most.

Comment: Are you using a commercially available Chinese proxy or did you just build one yourself? I might have some use for a Chinese proxy but my current VPN (Astrill)'s China server already died out. Just curious where did you get that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I simply looked up an anonymizer (a few actually) which had a server in China. It probably will protect itself from overload.